# Create a histogram of session length in a given time period using Keen IO

Tags: analytics, keen-io

We are trying to build a histogram of session length in a given time period.   Currently, we have sess:start and sess:end events which contains the session id and user id.  I am wondering what's the best way to compute this data?  Can this be achieve using the funnel api?

Answer (score 5):

Have you checkout out the [recipes section in Keen IO's docs](https://keen.io/docs/recipes/histograms/#histograms)? Here is an excerpt from the section on histogram recipes for Session Length that might be really helpful.

**Excerpt**

> To create a histogram for session lengths, like the one shown above,
>   you can run a count analysis on an event collection for completed
>   sessions (e.g. session_end). Along the x-axis you’ll have segments of
>   time lapsed in a session, and along the y-axis you’ll have the
>   percentage of sessions that fit into a given session length cohort.
>
> Note: this recipe incorporates the D3 histogram recipe, which is
>   explained further in the documentation.

```
histogram('chart-1', {
    segment_length: 60,  // In seconds
    data_points: 10,  // i.e. There will be 10 bars on our chart
    analysis_type: 'count',
    query_parameters: {
        event_collection: 'session_end',
        timeframe: timeframe,
        filters: []
    }
});
```

**More information**

- [Keen IO - Analytics for Developers](https://keen.io/)
- [Keen IO - Documentation](https://keen.io/docs/)
- Code excerpt: [Keen IO - Recipes for Histograms](https://keen.io/docs/recipes/histograms/#histograms)

Comment: the recipes link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good stuff behind the link that Stephanie posted.

One extra thing I'll venture is that putting an integer sess:length property in the sess:end event would make things easier. You'd have to keep the start time for each session somewhere in your database so that you can compute the difference for the sess:end event. But then you'd have the difference as a plain old number of seconds and can do any type of numerical analysis on it.