# Keen.IO - Bucketing results by numeric value rather than time / Histogram

Tags: histogram, keen-io, buckets

Working with the Keen.io API,
I have an event with a numeric parameter, and would like to bucketize the results over the range of values of the parameter.  For example, session-duration: I'd like to count the number of session durations which occur in each of say 20 buckets over the range of the values.  Another way to look at this would be to produce a histogram of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a histogram of session length in a given time period using Keen IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619758/create-a-histogram-of-session-length-in-a-given-time-period-using-keen-io)

Comment: after i thought to look for 'histogram' i found this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619758/create-a-histogram-of-session-length-in-a-given-time-period-using-keen-io which seems like exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 1):

There's a histogram recipe that could be adapted to create the buckets over a range view that you're looking for. The recipe uses Keen IO’s JavaScript data visualization library:

The code is located in this GitHub gist: https://gist.github.com/dustinlarimer/6b928c48abf803109ede.